# Mongod crashes on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm working on an app backed by mongodb. Interacting with the db server works fine whether from the shell or programmatically from the app. The problem is it works only if I run the server as root. It doesn't work otherwise. I don't have this problem when working on windows. I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

First, it was the db path, I changed the config file. Then it told me it can't create the lock file, and I changed permissions, (I'm not sure if this is good practice,) and now I have this error:

```
Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-04-29T21:22:44.897+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2017-04-29T21:22:44.897+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2017-04-29T21:22:44.897+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2017-04-29T21:22:44.897+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=413M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-04-29T21:22:44.922+0100 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1493497364:922160][28430:0x7f168c50dcc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2017-04-29T21:22:44.924+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:1: Operation not permitted src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267
2017-04-29T21:22:44.924+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 1: Operation not permitted, terminating
```

Also, when I try to run it as service, `service mongod start`, it throws an error that there are no such service file. I created a mongod.service file in the /etc/systemd/system dir but it still gives the same error, no such file.

Here is the result of `systemctl status mongod`:

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since ح 2017-04-30 00:15:00 WEST; 14h ago
  Process: 958 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 958 (code=exited, status=100)

أبر 30 00:15:00 archer09 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
أبر 30 00:15:00 archer09 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
أبر 30 00:15:00 archer09 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
أبر 30 00:15:00 archer09 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
أبر 30 00:15:00 archer09 systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Service.
أبر 30 00:15:00 archer09 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
أبر 30 00:15:00 archer09 systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Service.
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.

`sudo systemctl start mongod` does not seem to work in my environment.

Try `sudo service mongod start` it solved the issue on my end.

using  `sudo systemctl status mongod`

Gave me;

```
mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-01-24 13:01:38 UTC; 44min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 23900 (mongod)
    Tasks: 25
   Memory: 143.9M
      CPU: 8.935s
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─23900 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```